# Why is Robot Method to take screenshot is saving a black image?

Tags: java

I am trying to capture the screen shot of a HTML page . When i run the application in local host i am getting proper image saved . But when i run application in server i am getting a black image saved .  can anyone please tell me why this is happening. Thanks in advance.

```
   try {            
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        String format = "jpg";
        String fileName = "FullScreenshot." + format;

        Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        BufferedImage screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
        ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, format, new File("H:\\" + fileName));

        System.out.println("A full screenshot saved!");
      }
   catch (IOException ex) 
      {
        System.err.println(ex);
      }
```

Comment: Are you running that code on your desktop or is that a remote or headless machine?

Comment: I am running that code on desktop

Comment: excuse me are you taking a picture of the screen in front of you that is connected to the computer you are typing in?? if "server" is some kind of keyboard I'm sorry you will not capture anything